# Proving that Span{u, w} = Span{2u − w, w}

Tags: linear-algebra

Proving that Span{u, w} = Span{2u − w, w}, for all $u, w ∈ R^3$.

Let
$u=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$
$w = \begin{pmatrix} d \\ e \\ f \end{pmatrix}$

$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 ∈ R$

$$x_1 \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} + x_2 \begin{pmatrix} d \\ e \\ f \end{pmatrix} = x_3 \begin{pmatrix}2a-d\\ 2b-e\\ 2c-f\end{pmatrix} + x_4\begin{pmatrix}d\\ e\\ f\end{pmatrix}$$

When $x_1=2, x_2=0, x_3=1, x_4=1$, we get:

$\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\ 2b\\ 2c\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}2a-d+d\\ 2b-e+e\\ 2c-f+f\end{pmatrix}$

And therefore $\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\ 2b\\ 2c\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\ 2b\\ 2c\end{pmatrix}$

Is this proof sufficient enough?

Comment: Does the context of this exercise specifically ask you to prove it for vectors in $\Bbb R^3$? The equality of spans is valid in any vector space (over the reals, or any field of characteristic not equal to $2$), and the general proof is probably more illuminating than using coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes, it's specifically for ℝ3.

Comment: You only prove it for a special case. You need to prove there exist $x_3, x_4$ for every $x_1, x_2$ and conversly there exist $x_1, x_2$ for every $x_3, x_4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said, you need to prove there is a bijection (or bi-inclusion) between $\text{Span}\{u, w\}$ and $\text{Span}\{2u-w, w\}$. So we need to show that every $v \in \text{Span}\{u, w\}$ is also part of $\text{Span}\{2u-w, w\}$ and vice-versa.

Let $v \in \text{Span}\{u, w\}$, then there exist $x_1, x_2$ such that 
$$v = x_1 u + x_2 w.$$
We need to find $x_3$ and $x_4$ such that
$$v = x_3 (2u-w) + x_4 w.$$
Consider $x_3 = \frac{x_1}{2}$ and $x_4=x_2+\frac{x_1}{2}$
Then
$$\dfrac{x_1}{2} (2u-w) + \left(x_2 + \dfrac{x_1}{2}\right) w$$
$$\left(2\cdot\dfrac{x_1}{2}\right)u - \dfrac{x_1}{2} w + x_2 w + \dfrac{x_1}{2}w$$
$$x_1u + x_2 w$$
which is equal to $v$. Thhsu $v\in \text{Span}\{2u-w,w\}$ and $\text{Span}\{u,w\} \subset \text{Span}\{2u-w,w\}$

Conversly, let $v \in \text{Span}\{2u-w,w\}$, then there exist $x_3, x_4$ such that
$$v = x_3(2u-w) + x_4w$$
Since
$$v = x_3(2u-w) + x_4w = (2x_3)u + (x_4-x_3)w$$
$v \in \text{Span\{u,w\}}$. Thus $\text{Span}\{2u-w,w\} \subset \text{Span}\{u,w\}$

Conclusion $\text{Span}\{u, w\} = \text{Span}\{2u-w, w\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x_1,x_2$ you need to find $x_3,x_4$ such that your equation is satisfied. Then you know $span(u,w)\subset span(2u-w,w)$ and still have to show $span(2u-w,w)\subset(u,w)$.

Comment: Why showing that the spans are equal to each other like I showed is not enough?

Comment: You just showed it for one specific choice of $x_1, x_2$ resp.  $x_3,x_4$.

Comment: How do I show it for any ?

Comment: For example: the equation $x_1(2u-w)+x_2w=(2x_1) u +(-x_1+x_2)w$ shows that any linear combination of $2u-w$ and $w$ can be expressed as linear combination of $u$ and $w$. The equation explicitely gives you a formula of how the new coefficients for $u$ and $w$ can be chosen. Thus $span(2u-w,w)\subset span(u,w)$. And btw a linear bijection only would show the two spans have the same dimension.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not a completed proof; you should show that, there exists a bijection between span(u,w) and span(2u - w, w)

Comment: What does bijection have to do with anything (as opposed to bi-inclusion)?